# Fallout shelter: Updated room produce less than before

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm new at Fallout Shelter and every time I create a new Vault, I have problem to get enough resource. 
So, on my last game, I'm full focused on resources rooms. For each resource I have 2 merged room, updated one time and always full. On stat I had something like 9.5 Water production / minute, and when I have updated this room again I got 7.0 Water production / minute..
WT. ?! Which game give you a worth production when you update it? 
I was full stock and now everyone is dead, cause I got no more caps (update cost 1125, all my save).

What do I have to do to grow up my production ??

Comment: I'm not sure about a room producing less than before, but I've got a few vaults up to 100 dwellers, and I always have to rush a lot at the beginning. Don't expect your rooms to produce enough right off the bat without rushing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check your dweller stats? The higher the appropriate stat is, the faster the individuals in the room work. So take a water treatment plant. If your perception in the room is now **lower** than it was in your other room, the production time will be longer. You can fix early in the game by making your dweller wear outfits you collect to push the appropriate stat. Later, you can raise them using the training rooms.

On top of this, the happiness of your dwellers will all increase the amount of bonus resources you get.

Comment: Both stats was given with exactly the same sweller stats, it was taken just before and after the update

Comment: Maybe you had some bug prior to the update, which has been fixed :/

Comment: This game is bad handled with resources.. All my stats say I produce more than I use, but green bar is reducing..

Comment: @Arthur Are you sure the -total- stats add up to the **exact** same? That seems unlikely with the RNG for dwellers. Early in the game you won't see it, but at higher levels there's a diminishing return on how fast a room can be sped up.

Comment: @Trasiva, I put the maxed stats i can for each resources. And I didn't move dwellers, so i'm sure than the stats isthe same

Comment: @Arthur The solution then is to note the -total- stat for that room, and then create another vault, and reproduce that stat total there and see if it is the same. However, you're not likely to get a different answer from the one I've given, so if you'd accept it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Trasiva, i'm not talking about another vault, i just note the production before uptading, and after. without any other change.. The new vault is because all my dweller was dead cause of this poduction down. So you say me, ther are no solution, the best way is not to update your room cause of bug ?

Comment: @Arthur What I'm saying is, if it was a bug for some reason and it's fixed, you're going to just have to move forward. My recommendation from this point forward is to make your production rooms into the three room combination, and max it out. Not upgrading your rooms does you more disservice than help.

Comment: @Trasiva, Ok you convinced me, I uninstall this game now. Worse resource management in all games lifes.

Comment: @Arthur Your consumption of resources does not stay the same.. If you add more people or more rooms they will consume more resources.. You cant just make one room and expect it to last while other things change.

Comment: @James He's saying the rate of resources generated changed. Not the consumption rate. As for the one room comment, One maxed out three room water treatment plant sustained my entire vault until I swapped it out with a maxed out three room water purification plant. That sustained me up to 100, when I've removed it for a single nuka cola plant for space. From what I've estimated, two maxed nuclear reactors, and four maxed nuca-cola plants can sustain a max vault without issue.

Comment: @Trasiva Yeah I only have one water plant as well and it runs on a narrow margin while I near in on 100 vault dwellers again. Anywho, from what I read he was confused on how the game works, some screen shots showing said oddity might be useful but I think he already gave up.

Comment: It's worth noting that Luck and Gear both ALSO affect production. If you have a naked dude w/ A=10 working and replace him with a A=10 and L=10 dweller, and she's wearing the +7 Handyman outfit production will more than double!

Comment: @aslum Gear was noted in my answer. Luck doesn't affect production, it just increases the chance for caps as well as lowering the risk on rushing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I first started. I started over like 3 times. Like what the answer says above matters also don't over do the rooms always make sure you have enough people to each room. When making babies do it one at a time. Don't make the rooms bigger unless you have enough people. Basically don't over do it. Patience is key.

Answer (score 1):

[Extensive research on room production.](http://m.imgur.com/a/XpGk3)

Some width 2 rooms produce more then width 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even when you produce more than you consume, you cannot store it, or you are not collecting it while you are online. This was a problem for me in the early stages.. And if that is not the problem you might want to check that you are matching the right dwellers with the right room (for example; a dweller with a lot of agility, or A, would match with the diner, while someone with High strength, or S, would match with a power plant) I know this sounds basic and easy, but I have seen this issue a number of times, just make sure you double check.

Comment: I'm 100% sure..